# Is a Java SDK like JSforce available?

Tags: rest-api, java

I am working to integrate my Java application with Salesforce Service Cloud.

Searching about it, I saw that there is a very nice JS library, JSforce but I could not find anything similar for Java.

Do you know if such library exists for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Java WSC (webservice connector)

https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc

I have used it in past , pretty much gives you all the methods that are available in SOAP api, but its not as verse as JSForce.

Comment: it's shameful that that's the official way to connect to salesforce on java

Answer (score 0):

There is FuelSDK.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java

This SDK is more complete than the accepted answer (which is now outdated).

From the link:

> The Salesforce Marketing Cloud Java SDK enables developers to easily access the Salesforce Marketing Cloud (formerly ExactTarget) via the Java platform. Among other things, the SDK:
>
> - automatically acquires and refreshes Marketing Cloud access tokens
> - enables developers to access both Marketing Cloud SOAP and REST APIs in the same session
> - exposes simplified versions of the most commonly used Marketing Cloud objects and methods as Java native objects
> - provides passthroughs so developers can access the full REST and SOAP APIs directly when they need to go beyond the simplified interfaces
> - adds "sugar" methods for the most commonly used Marketing Cloud features that make it easy to use those features (e.g., the SDK provides a SQL-like interface to data extensions)